# How to remove gaps between cols in Bootstrap 4 and take full width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

another question here about Bootstrap 4.

I want to touch two images against each other and take up the full width of the page. I've tried container-fluid and img-fluid as I would think this would take up 100% of the width of the screen and then put them in 2 col-6's. Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Here is a visual example of what I want + code that I currently have:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmK7A.jpg)

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to remove the padding of `container-fluid`, use `!important` in CSS.

Comment: Or try to remove the padding of columns too using bootstrap class `p-0`.

Comment: @Ishaan I have answered already and you edited your comment to add `p-0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `p-0` of bootstrap which will remove padding on container-fluid and will show images on width and screen.

You do not need to do any custom CSS to do this.

Run snippet below.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added p-0 and it removed the outer white space but now I still have a space between the two images. Is there any way to fix this as well? Thanks!

Comment: Oh nevermind I got it! I just added p-0 also to the col's and that did it for me! Thanks!

Comment: @Nielsi_ Glad to hear that.

Comment: I have one more small issue. I want to change the height of the image like the image example above but whenever I change it with CSS it goes wrong. Do you maybe know a solution for this?

Comment: @Nielsi_ It would be ideal if you post this another question and explain and add details about this a little more. I am not sure what you mean. sorry.

Comment: Made a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730218/how-to-size-down-the-height-of-images-in-bootstrap-4