# How to decrease the height of images in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to decrease the the height a bit so that the image fits better on my page.
An example of what I mean: [image]

I tried to use custom CSS to change the height but then my images look strange and out of place.

My HTML:

```html
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid p-0 mt-2">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187622/pexels-photo-2187622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
      </div>
```

Comment: What you say size you mean the width and height of the each image ?

Comment: Do you want to align the images side by side?

Comment: The width is fine as it should take up 50/50 of the space but the image is quite large in height. I would like to make the image height smaller like in the example image. If you run the code snippet in full screen you will see that the images are large. I hope this explains enough I am still a beginner so I'm sorry if something is unclear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for

```css
.h-200 {
  height: 200px;
}

img.image {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid p-0 mt-2">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-200">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187605/pexels-photo-2187605.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 p-0 h-200">
      <img class="img-fluid image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187622/pexels-photo-2187622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
  </div>
```

Link to the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6hpsoynf/1/